# PyPI package can't find functions in said package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I made a python package called 'pyutils39'. So far it has functions consoleask(question) and reverse(text). It seemed to upload OK and has a page on pypi. (https://pypi.org/project/pyutils39).

**My Issue**

For testing, I installed my package  with `.\pip install pyutils39`. It seemed to install successfully, and going into \Lib\site-packages\pyutils39 does have the file. However, when I run my testing file, it crashes with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<MY USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = pyutils39.consoleask("Do you want to reverse hello?")
AttributeError: module 'pyutils39' has no attribute 'consoleask'
```

Completely removing all traces of the package makes it error with 'Module Not Found' (expected). Putting the package file in the same folder as the testing file works just fine.

**What I have Tried**

I have reinstalled my package, remade the testing file, and searched both google and stack overflow for this issue when nothing worked.

**Code**

Main file:

```
def reverse(data):
    x = str(data)
    datalen = len(data)
    x = x[datalen::-1]
    return x
def consoleask(question):
    while True:
        print(str(question)+' (Y/N)')
        x = input()
        if x.lower().startswith('y'):
            return True
            break
        elif x.lower().startswith('n'):
            return False
            break
```

Testing File

```
import pyutils39
x = pyutils39.consoleask("Do you want to reverse hello?")
if x == True:
    print(pyutils39.reverse("hello"))
```

Setup.py

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="pyutils39",
    version="0.1.3",
    author="Enderbyte09",
    author_email="enderbyte09@gmail.com",
    description="A utilities package",
    long_description=long_description,
    py_modules=['/src/pyutils39/pyutils39.py'],
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/Enderbyte-Programs/pyutils39",
    project_urls={
        "Bug Tracker": "https://github.com/Enderbyte-Programs/pyutils39/issues",
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="src"),
    python_requires=">=3.8",
```

)

I am still new to stackoverflow, so if there is any way to improve my question, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `setup.py` using wrong directives for package sources.
In `setup()` call, use `py_modules=['pyutils39.py']` - `py_modules` is used to declare single-file modules. Now it probably uses `packages` or a similar parameter, declaring the whole directory as a module. It's hard to make a more informed guess because `setup.py` is missing in the repo.

With the current layout, this will probably work:

```
from pyutils39 import pyutils39
```

Comment: I have added my setup.py. Where is the correct place to put the py_modules=[]? In addition, when I put a path to a file in py_modules, it returns this exception
`error: package directory '/src/pyutils39/pyutils39' does not exist

ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist`

Comment: @Enderbyte09 can you add setup.py to the repository? I'll make a pull request then

Comment: I have added latest versions to the repo

Comment: @Enderbyte09 [PR#1](https://github.com/Enderbyte-Programs/pyutils39/pull/1)