# I installed my package using pip and it didnt regocnise the module name

Tags: python, module, pip, packaging, pypi

**My Issue**

I installed the module suing pip and it installed fine however it says that the module is not found when I try to import it

pip install:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ school-algorithms==0.0.1
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting school-algorithms==0.0.1
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/67/860117a573abb5f62b46f83398f74140d8f033b467f81b940ce5216c39e5/school_algorithms-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.4 kB)
Installing collected packages: school-algorithms
Successfully installed school-algorithms-0.0.1
```

import:

```
>>> import school_algorithms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'school_algorithms'
```

**setup.cfg**

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name = "school_algorithms",
    version = "0.0.1",
    author = "Sammy Garcia",
    author_email = "s@mmygarcia.com",
    description = "School algorithm module for Python",
    long_description = long_description,
    py_modules = ["school_algorithms"],
    long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
    url = "https://github.com/Sammygarch/school-algorithms.git",
    project_urls = {
        "Bug Tracker": "https://github.com/Sammygarch/school-algorithms/issues"
    },
    classifiers = [
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License"
    ],
    python_requires = ">=3.6",
)
```

I have seen a similar problem here: [PyPI package can't find functions in said package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170179/pypi-package-cant-find-functions-in-said-package) that told me to add the py_modules = [package_name] but that doesnt work

**The main code**

```
from math import sqrt

def _if_not_int_or_float_raise(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if type(arg) != int and type(arg) != float:
            raise ValueError ("At least one of the values wasn't an integer or a floar.")

def power_calc(E, t):
    """
    Calculates power from energy and time using the formula:
        power = energy / time

    Args:
        E (int or float): The energy value in the equation
        t (int or float): The time value of the equation

    Returns:
        E / t  : (float)

    Raises:
        ValueError: If E or t is not an integer or float

    """
    _if_not_int_or_float_raise(E, t)
    return E / t

def energy_calc(p, t):
    """
    Calculates energy from power and time using the formula:
        energy = power * time

    Args:
        p (int or float): The power value of the equation
        t (int or float): The time value of the equation

    Returns:
        p * t

    Raises:
        ValueError: If p or t is not an integer or float

    """
    _if_not_int_or_float_raise(p, t)
    return p * t

def time_calc(p, E):
    """
    Calculates time from power and energy using the formula:
        time = energy / power

    Args:
        p (int or float): The power value of the equation
        E (int or float): The energy value of the equaton

    Returns:
        E / p

    Raises:
        ValueError: If p or E is not an integer or float

    """
    _if_not_int_or_float_raise(p, E)
    return E / p

def pythag_hypot(a, b):
    """
    Calculates the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle using the formula:
        hypotenuse = the square-root of (leg(a) squared + leg(b) squared)

    Args:
        a (int or float): leg(a) of the equation
        b (int or float): leg(b) of the equation

    Returns:
        sqrt(a**2 + b**2)

    Raises:
        ValueError: If a or b is not an integer or float

    """
    _if_not_int_or_float_raise(a, b)
    return sqrt(a**2 + b**2)

def pythag_leg(hy, a):
    """
    Calculates the length of a leg in right-angled triangle using the formula:
        leg(b) = the square-root of (hy squared - leg(a) squared)

    Args:
        hy: the hypotneus of the equation
        a: the leg of the equation

    Returns:
        sqrt(a**2 + b**2)

    Raises:
        ValueError: If hy or a is not an integer or float

    """
    _if_not_int_or_float_raise(hy, a)
    return sqrt(hy**2 - a**2)

def triangle_area(b, h):
    """
    Calculates the  area of a triangle using the formula:
        area = 0.5(base * height)

    Args:
        b(int or float): the base in the equation
        h(int or float): the height in the equation

    Returns:
        (b*h) / 2

    Raises:
        ValueError: If hy or a is not an integer or float
    """
    _if_not_int_or_float_raise(b, h)
    return (b*h) / 2
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Are you running the command in a virtual environment?

Comment: @Cameron yes it was in a virtural environment

Comment: If you are using a python virtual environment, you could look in `environment_name/Lib/site-packages` and see if the package is there, and if so, if you are spelling the module name correctly.

Comment: @Cameron I have checked and yes it is in the virtual environment